# Use Chrome Driver, without Chrome knowing, that automated software controls Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, splinter

Specifically, I want to use splinter (built on top of selenium) to automate a process on a website. The website in question has a ReCaptcha by the end of the automation process. It seems, that the ReCaptcha won't show up when I use the chrome driver. Is there any way to work around this? I have no problem solving the captchas myself.

Comment: Mind give us an example of the website in question? I don't believe the message will effect the captcha to not show up